# PrototypeJS: Wildcard 'starts-with' id selector?

Tags: css-selectors, prototypejs, wildcard

Using JQuery this can be achieved with:

```
$("[id^='thestart']");
```

Can this be achieved with Prototype-JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using '$$':

```
$$("[id^='thestart']")
```

Just keep in mind that unlike '$', '$$' return an array of elements.